# Как выйти из php.exe в консоли

Tags: php

Вопрос может показаться глупым, но я выполнил в командной строке команду

```
    php
```

Теперь как мне выйти из него? Пробую вводить команды, не реагирует.

P.S возможности закрыть консоль нет

Comment: CTRL+C или Ctrl+Z всего-навсего ))

Comment: ctrl+Z - это не выйти, это отправить в фон. А вот есть Ctrl+D - это честный способ сказать "конец файла", после чего все и закроется.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 3):

используйте Ctrl+D для выхода из режима php